# How can I get tightvnc to start automatically on startup?

Tags: raspbian, boot, vnc

I have tightvnc installed and working on my Raspberry Pi. I intend to use the Pi via VNC from my Mac. Is there a way to auto start tightvnc when the Pi boots up as then I wont have to have a separate monitor, keyboard and mouse connected to the pi when it starts.

I have Raspbian installed from the latest NOOBS software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a script which starts tightvnc and copy it to /etc/services/ but you have to mark it executable with chmod 775 as example

Alternatively you could ssh into your pi and start tightvnc manually

Comment: Your suggestion for sshing to the pi and starting it manually works a treat

Answer (score 4):

1. Create the following new file `/etc/init.d/tightvnc`:

   ```
    #!/bin/sh
    ### BEGIN INIT INFO
    # Provides:          tightvncserver
    # Required-Start:    $local_fs
    # Required-Stop:     $local_fs
    # Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
    # Default-Stop:      0 1 6
    # Short-Description: Start/stop tightvncserver
    ### END INIT INFO

    # Set the USER variable to the name of the user to start tightvncserver under
    export USER='pi'

    eval cd ~$USER

    case "$1" in
      start)
        su $USER -c '/usr/bin/tightvncserver :1'
        echo "Starting TightVNC server for $USER "
        ;;
      stop)
        pkill Xtightvnc
        echo "Tightvncserver stopped"
        ;;
      *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/tightvnc {start|stop}"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
    exit 0
   ```

   Remember to change the `USER` variable (don't make it root!)
2. Change the permissions so that the file can be executed:

   ```
    sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/tightvnc
   ```
3. Make the script executed at boot time

   ```
    update-rc.d tightvnc defaults
   ```
4. Reboot the RPi to check if it runs.

Sources: http://elinux.org/RPi_VNC_Server & http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/tightvnc

Comment: The above works, *if* you change: `update-rc.d /etc/init.d/tightvnc defaults` to: `update-rc.d tightvnc defaults`.

Comment: Why doesn't it work with the full path specified? Also, this would only work if the path to `tightvnc` is in `$PATH`

Comment: @Greenonline That's not how `update-rc.d` works.  Read the first sentence of `man update-rc.d`: https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/sysv-rc/update-rc.d.8.en.html I don't know if it is smart enough to catch someone using an absolute path, if not, using one won't work, so best practice would be to not use one.

Comment: @goldilocks - ok, yeah, thanks. Wasn't thinking straight :-)

Comment: The spaces before code, one space each row, makes the file not accepted.